# mysql trigger query. Is it correct?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update mysql table on Insert command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946137/update-mysql-table-on-insert-command)

Below is the query I am using to insert a new row in send_sms table:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert;

BEFORE UPDATE ON send_sms

  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 

    INSERT INTO send_sms 
      (sender, receiver, msgdata)
    VALUES 
      ('123456', '654321', 'hello trigger')

  END

DELIMITER ;
```

...before an Insert query is executed on send_sms table. Am I doing it right? Because I am not getting what I want.

Comment: you want to insert into `send_sms` on the before insert trigger for the same table?

Comment: it does not work even If insert into some other table in same database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is not working because there are syntax errors, here is the correct version

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert  -- remove ;
AFTER INSERT ON table_first
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO table_second 
      (value1, rvalue2, value3)
    VALUES 
      ('123456', '654321', 'hello trigger');    -- add ;
  END
$$ -- add $$

DELIMITER ;
```