# Update mysql table on Insert command

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a situation in which I want to update a the second table when a row of data is inserted in the first table. To achieve this I am using mysql triggers and below is the query I am using, but its not working for me.

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert;

AFTER INSERT ON table_first

  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 

    INSERT INTO table_second 
      (value1, rvalue2, value3)
    VALUES 
      ('123456', '654321', 'hello trigger')

  END

DELIMITER ;
```

Both the tables exists in the same database. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some small syntax problems ... here :

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert  -- remove ;
AFTER INSERT ON table_first
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO table_second 
      (value1, rvalue2, value3)
    VALUES 
      ('123456', '654321', 'hello trigger');    -- add ;
  END
$$ -- add $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly. Now can you please tell me one more thing? Suppose there is a column gender in the first table and I want that the INSERT query of the trigger runs only if the gender is 'Male'. I tried IF NEW.gender=='MALE' "Do Something" END IF, but it does not work. Thanks

Comment: The equality operator in SQL is "=", not "=="... (yeah, you got to switch the habits if you did some C/php/python/etc lately)